# Constructor class thread safety in Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, thread-safety

Using `Java` **reflection**, one can instantiate an object of a class, even via a private constructor, e.g. for

```
public class MyClass
{
    private MyClass(Object p1, String p2)
    {
        // Constructor with no modifications to static code
    }
}
```

one can do (in the same or any other class, exception handling omitted for simplification)

```
public static final Constructor myClass;

static
{
    myClass = MyClass.class.getConstructor(Object.class, String.class);
    myClass.setAccessible(true);
}
```

and then create new instances of `MyClass` like

```
    myClass.newInstance(new Object(), "Test");
```

Is the above call to `newInstance()` thread-safe, given that `myClass` is static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `Constructor.newInstance()` does not seem to be *strictly* thread-safe; at least in my openjdk-6 implementation I find a class `sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl` having a field defined as `private int numInvocations;` and later on this line of code: `if (++numInvocations > ReflectionFactory.inflationThreshold()) {` - which may certainly behave otherwise as expected.
Also, in the `Constructor` class itself, the method `acquireConstructorAccessor()` is documented with "NOTE that there is no synchronization used here".

But the dodgy behaviour does not seem to result in an overall unexpected behavior, only doing things repeatedly/unnecessarily, thus calling `newInstance()` in parallel would NOT result in something being screwed up.

Obviously, you can still mess things up with what's done within the instance constructor.

Comment: Hmmm... Weird.One would assume that newInstance() is as thread-safe as an actual constructor.

Comment: Well, would be nice, I agree. But the amount of code being involved is obvioulsy a bit more compared to a direct call...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the class instance is static, and the constructor is thread safe, as long as it is not doing anything non-thread safe with the static context of the object.

Comment: This is my assumption, too. I will clarify the question. +1.