# Are java.lang.Class methods thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

Under IBM JVM we have faced an issue when multiple threads are trying to call Class.getAnnotation at the same time on different objects (but with the same annotation). Threads are starting to deadlock waiting on a monitor inside a Hashtable, which is used as a cache for annotations in IBM JVM. The weirdest thing is that the thread that is holding this monitor is put into 'waiting on condition' state right inside Hashtable.get, making all other threads to wait indefinitely.

The support from IBM stated, that implementation of Class.getAnnotation is not thread safe.

Comparing to other JVM implementations (for example, OpenJDK) we see that they implement Class methods in thread safe manner. IBM JVM is a closed source JVM, they do publish some source code together with their JVM, but it's not enough to make a clear judgment whenever their implementation of Class is thread safe or not.

The Class documentation doesn't clearly state whenever its methods are thread safe or not. So is it a safe assumption to treat Class methods (getAnnotation in particular) as a thread safe or we must use sync blocks in multi threaded environment?

How do popular frameworks (ex. Hibernate) are mitigating this problem? We haven't found any usage of synchronization in Hibernate code that was using getAnnotation method.

Comment: While a good question, it might be too opinionated for this forum. `so who is wrong here?`

Comment: You're saying OpenJDK, but IBM JVM. Which implementation are you actually using?

Comment: As one of my mentors once said to me:  "The code doesn't lie."  If that's what you're seeing in the source, then that's what's happening.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think the OP's point is that the OpenJDK implementation is thread safe, which suggests that `Class` is _supposed_ to be thread safe. But the OP is trying to verify this before complaining to IBM that their implementation isn't thread-safe. OP, is that abotu right?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, IBM JVM is a closed source, unfortunatly. IBM disclosed some source code, but it's not enought to understand whenever their Class implementation is thread safe or not.

Comment: `Class` doesn't seem to make any guarantees.

Comment: I think that you miss read something. The access to `object.class` is thread safe, but not to particular method of it.

Comment: Judging by some other questions, in particular [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795637/constructor-class-thread-safety-in-java-reflection) even OpenJDK doesn't guarantee thread safety of Class and all it's fields and methods.

Comment: Oracle made it synchronized, it should be the reference implementation? => "private synchronized void initAnnotationsIfNecessary() " in JSE7 sources

Comment: @pdem: Unless some behaviour is guaranteed by the API documentation or language specification, it is completely irrelevant how it is implemented in Oracle's API implementation.

Comment: @jarnbjo Oracle's implementation is a de-facto standard.  If you want to sell a JDK or a JRE that diverges from Oracle's in some significant way, even if yours is a technically correct implementation of the _published_ standard, then you do so at your own risk.

Comment: If they claim it is not thread safe, why did they use the thread safe collection Hashtable?  This sounds like a bug.  There is no obvious reason you should lock an immutable object to make it thread safe.

Comment: @jameslarge: That's rubbish. There are several differences in the details between the Oracle API implementation and the implementations from 3rd party vendors. It's not a problem unless ignorant developers with your attitude make it a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is no specified behavior, so *normally* the correct way to deal with it would be to say “if no behavior is specified, assume no safety guarantees”.

But…

The problem here is that if these methods are not thread-safe, the specification lacks a documentation of how to achieve thread-safety correctly here. Recall that instances of `java.lang.Class` are visible across all threads of the entire application or even within multiple applications if your JVM hosts multiple apps/applets/servlets/beans/etc.

So unlike classes you instantiate for your own use where you can control access to these instances, you can’t preclude other threads from accessing the same methods of a particular `java.lang.Class` instance. So even if we engage with the *very awkward* concept of relying on some kind of *convention* for accessing such a global resource (e.g. like saying “the caller has to do `synchronized(x.class)`”), the problem here is, even bigger, that no such convention exists (well, or isn’t documented which comes down to the same).

So in this special case, where no caller’s responsibility is documented and can’t be established without such a documentation, IBM is in charge of telling how they think, programmers should use these methods correctly when they are implemented in a non-thread-safe manner.

---

There is an alternative interpretation I want to add: all information, `java.lang.Class` offers, is of a static constant nature. This class reflects what has been invariably compiled into the class. And it has no methods to alter any state. So maybe there’s no additional thread-safety documentation as all information is to be considered *immutable* and hence naturally thread-safe.

Rather, the fact that under the hood some information is loaded on demand is the undocumented implementation detail that the programmer does not need to be aware of. So if JRE developers decide to implement lazy creation for efficiency they *must* maintain the like-immutable behavior, read thread safety.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem might be related to bug fixed in version 8 of Oracle Java.

> One thread calls isAnnotationPresent on an annotated class where the
>   annotation is not yet initialised for its defining classloader. This
>   will result in a call on AnnotationType.getInstance, locking the class
>   object for sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType. getInstance will
>   result in a Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary for that annotation,
>   trying to acquire a lock on the class object of that annotation.
>
> In the meanwhile, another thread has requested Class.getAnnotations
>   for that annotation(!). Since getAnnotations locks the class object it
>   was requested on, the first thread can't lock it when it runs into
>   Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary for that annotation. But the thread
>   holding the lock will try to acquire the lock for the class object of
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType in AnnotationType.getInstance
>   which is hold by the first thread, thus resulting in the deadlock.

[JDK-7122142 : (ann) Race condition between isAnnotationPresent and getAnnotations](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7122142)

Comment: This is not exactly our case - in our case all classes are already loaded (our code hangs after running for couple of hours), whereas in the bug stacktrace JVM tries to load annotation class for the first time and deadlocks.

Comment: In such case you should try to contact the IBM Support team or use Health Center to diagnose that is the problem.

Comment: We did contact IBM Support and they said that class.getAnnotation is not thread safe in IBM JVM. This is why I opened this question - to get opinions whenever we can expect Class methods to be thread safe or not, giving the fact that in other JVM they are.

Comment: This question sould be posted on some IBM user group or bug trace. The Stack is not the best place for discussion as this is more question and answer.

Comment: Since the problem is related to the IBM VM, I don't understand why a bug in Oracle's VM should be relevant here?